# Suggestions on Harmonic Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am about to finish Hewitt's book on Real and Abstract Analysis. I have alredy got a glimpse of what Functional Analysis is and got quite interested in it to the point of rediscovering/proving myself some "lighter" results like Dini's Theorem (before reading that remark in Hewitt's book). However, some of my teachers have told me about Harmonic/Fourier Analysis and its connection to number theory, my other great interest. None of my teachers works in Harmonic Analysis and I would like to listen to some first hand experience and get some idea of what type of theorems one should expect and how fertile the subject is. I would also thank any book/notes/lectures suggentions.

(I know analysis up to Hewitt's Real and Abstract Analysis -and some complex analysis too-. I have also studied a bit on PDE's and a fair ammount of number theory as well.)